# Was Ming the Merciless the only Major Enemy of Flash Gordon?

Tags: comics, flash-gordon

I haven't seen all the *Flash Gordon* comics.  I have seen the serials, but I know the serials were based very closely on the comics, so the comic books would be the primary source for any *Flash Gordon* stories.

I know Flash faced different "minor" enemies, mostly on Mongo.  Often they were princes or princesses who didn't want him trespassing on their land, but often he ended up making friends and turning these minor enemies into allies.

Throughout the comics that I've read, the major villain, always overshadowing everything Flash, Dale, and Dr. Zarkov do, is Ming the Merciless.  Is he the only major enemy Flash ever faced?

By major and minor, I'm thinking about how Flash, even when Flash was in trouble with a minor villain, he still had to deal with the real big bad guy, Ming — so were there ever any other major bad guys other than Ming?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flash's main "Big Bad" was Ming.  Pretty much everything was directly or indirectly related to him.

In part this is because they were almost always trapped on Mongo, which was Ming's planet.

In comparison, the contemporaneous Buck Rogers comic strip went through several Big-Bads during the decades it was published.

Comment: Are you going to answer **all** my questions?  Seriously, this is what I thought, but I haven't read all of Flash.  I'm not nearly as familiar with Buck as I am with Flash.

Comment: I'm not stalking you I promise!  I just have a thing for classic old-School Sci-Fi.

Comment: Well, that makes at least two of us on here.  I think a lot of classic and old school is neglected.  Even with _John Carter_ coming out in a few weeks, when I asked a Barsoom question, it was all but ignored.

Answer (score 6):

I have read some old Flash Gordon comics, from the 1960s, and there was another major villain he faced off against, numerous times.

An all conquering alien race - Skorpi, and their leader, Baron Dak Tula. 
They were an advanced race, with few paranormal powers, had mighty starships, though possibly not FTL equipped.

Dak Tula and Flash faced off on Earth, on the moons of Jupiter and also outside our solar system. There was even one incident, where Flash went into the past and scrambled Dak Tula's plans to take over the then Earth. That was many thousands of years in the past.

I have also read that the Baron saved Flash's life once, and an iconic statement from him goes somehow like this: "Ponder over this as you recover, Gordon. I have saved your life, but when the time is ripe, I will come back to claim it." Awesome.

This was the only link I found relevant.
http://golfcharliepapa.blogspot.in/2013/11/plagiarism-or-inspiration-curious-case.html

Please do more research if you are interested.